# default permissions for /var/www

Tags: permissions, apache2, php, chmod

I was trying to open a file and write to it with PHP at `/var/www`folder
but it wasn't working so I did

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/www
```

now I want to set the permissions for `/var/www` to the default.
what are the default permissions for `/var/www`?

Comment: I am not a member of serverfault so I could not comment or upvote the answer. But this post really nails it: http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver

Comment: Try to check the doc inside the wiki page: [File and Directory Ownership and Permissions for Web Content.](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/FileSystemPermissions)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The permissions on this folder are:

```
chmod 755 /var/www/
```

and the files inside the folder are:

```
chmod 644 /var/www/file
```

Answer (score 66):

The default permission for `/var/www` itself is a pretty standard one: owner `root:root` and mod `755`.

As for anything *inside* `/var/www`, that is one of the rare directories where you have the privilege of deciding for yourself what to put in it and what permissions everything in it should have.  But what makes the most sense is:

- Most files should be writable by whichever user or group is going to be writing to them most.  You can set them to be owned by your user account.  Or set up a custom group for your developers.  Or if the files will be modified rarely and you want good security, you can go with `root:root` and just sudo in on the rare occasions they'll be modified.
- Most files should *not* be world-writable.  So, `644` for files, and `755` for directories is appropriate (or `664` and `775` if you want to give a group write access).
- It is *not* recommended to set any of it to be writable by the web server, ie `www-data`, except for any specific files your web scripts to be able to write to.  If so, it's better to set the user or group of those files to `www-data` than to make them world-writable.  Note that any time the `www-data` user can write to any file within the web root, whether it's by setting the user or group on those files, or making them world-writable, it's a potential security problem.  World-writable is just the worse of the two.

Comment: Upvoted as most conclusive answer here

Comment: Now, this is a really good answer. :)

Comment: to improve the answer, consider adding commands to set the appropriate parmissions

Comment: Is there a recursive function that can change all folders to 755 and files to 644 inside var/www?

Comment: Yep: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817744/change-all-files-and-folders-permissions-of-a-directory-to-644-755 (the second answer is more elegant than the accepted one IMO)

Comment: So..... What should I do, then? Chown 755 /var/www/html or what ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're wanting to achieve but I gave a bunch of advice in the answer.  If you have a separate more specific question try asking it as a question.

Answer (score 13):

Make sure the group is www-data on '/var/www'.

```
sudo chgrp www-data /var/www
```

Make it writable

```
sudo chmod 775 /var/www
```

set group id for subfolders

```
sudo chmod g+s /var/www
```

add your username to the group

```
sudo useradd -G www-data [USERNAME]
OR
usermod -a -G www-data [USERNAME]
```

give yourself ownership

```
sudo chown [USERNAME] /var/www/
```

Comment: That is **not** the default permissions for /var/www, and it's a **very** bad idea security-wise to make the whole web root writable by www-data.  Only do this when web scripts need write access to particular files, and even so only do it to those particular files, not to the entire web root.  And the OP did not say he needed to do this, anyway, so this should not be a recommendation at all.

Comment: Also it's a very bad idea to add yourself to the www-data group and treat that group in that manner.  Where did you read to do this?  It's *particularly* bad advice, almost maliciously so.  Create your own groups when you need to give a group access to something: don't re-use the unprivileged groups that are intended for internal use by daemons.

Comment: @neon_overload what do you recommend

Comment: Exactly, what would your recommend @neon_overload?

Comment: @Banago personnaly I recommend a +1 :)

Comment: @Banago & aWebDeveloper did you see the answer I wrote to this question?  Still have questions?

Comment: @neon_overload, I did and it makes total sense. I was confused by the fast that /var/www was owned by root:root. But now permissions make a lot of sense to me. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo adduser $USER www-data
sudo chown root:root /var/www


sudo chown -R $USER:www-data /var/www/*
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

Comment: Depending on the contents, it may be harmful to use the `-R` flag here. Since the OP did not use the `-R` flag, we should not recommend it to correct the wrong permissions they created. The `-R` flag is rarely helpful!

Answer (score -1):

for what it's worth (I may be wrong-more testing to do) make sure that the files that you are transferring are "owned" by the user that logs in to BOTH machines. so for /var/www/website the webdir on the source machine is owned by kevin and the user on the dest machine was me too. i will do further testing once I have time. Thanks

Comment: This answer seems opinionated to me...