# Folder permissions changed

Tags: command-line, permissions, filesystem

I have very specific questions regarding permissions. I have delved into the FilePermissions Wiki - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Recently I installed an ecommerce open source software on my LAMP server. It needed some permissions to be given.These were the two lines I executed ,blindly, in the terminal for all the permissions it needed-

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data * -R
sudo usermod -a -G www-data $username
```

Please explain what these two lines of code did. The MAIN REASON I am posting this question is because *now* it has **locked some of my folders** How do I **revert all those permissions back to normal**? How would I know which folders' permission it has changed and what were their normal permissions? What is the difference between `chmod` and `chown` and which should be used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data * -R
```

The above command has changed ownership of all directories, sub-directories and files of your home directory from default to `www-data` user and `www-data` group

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data $username
```

This command has added a new user `www-data` and new group `www-data`.

You can revert changes back to normal by this command

```
sudo chown username:username * -R
```

Replace `username` with your actual **user_name**

`chmod` changes file and directory permissions whereas `chown` changes ownership.

Comment: @Faizen, I'm not entirely convinced that changing the ownership to the users name will revert things back to normal. Have you seen http://askubuntu.com/questions/386928/default-permissions-for-var-www ?

Comment: I second Elder Geek, altough if "blindly" in OP's question means "right after having opened the terminal" that *might* be the right solution. Not convinced of the second either tough.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

`usermod` The usermod command modifies the system account files to reflect the changes that are specified on the command line. as outlined in `man usermod`

`chown` changes ownership as outlined in `man chown`

Long answer:
`chown -R` operates recursively so `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data *`

changes ownership of every file from the **current directory** down through all it's subdirectories to be owned by user www-data and group www-data.

`usermod -a -G www-data $username` appends www-data to the groups to which $username belongs. Unless you have an environment variable that will be expanded you'll need to **replace $username with the actual username**.

**To return the permissions to defaults** please see [default permissions for /var/www](https://askubuntu.com/questions/386928/default-permissions-for-var-www)