# Ubuntu webserver permissions for writing

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, webserver

While setting up my webserver I gave all my public folders 777 permissions with filezilla, I found out that this is very bad because everyone can put stuff in that folder at the moment.
I have a website that has a fileupload form (laravel). I searched a bit around and found out I had to give the ['www-data'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/386928/default-permissions-for-var-www?rq=1) user the appropriate rights to write files.

So what is the www-data user? is it an user generated automaticly.

When changing permissions with an ftp client like filezilla to 777 whos permissoins am I setting ?

Comment: ***NEVER SET 777!*** If you are doing this, you're doing it **wrong** and don't have good permissions setups - time to redo your perms

Comment: @ThomasW. Thats exactly why i posted this question ;)

Comment: Please, Can you set here the routes/path to directory public?

Comment: @JoseCarlosRamosCarmenates /var/www/dmydomain.eu/public

Answer (score 0):

www-data is the user under which your Apache/Nginx runs.

Setting permissions to 777 grants read/write/execute access to the owner, the group and everyone else.

When only www-data needs access, you could change the owner of the file/folder and set permissions to something like 755.

This information might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions